# Why is there no `reduceByValue` in Spark collections?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Spark and Scala and keep coming across this pattern:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("data.txt")
val pairs = lines.map(s => (s, 1))
val counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

While I understand what it does, I don't understand why it is used instead of having something like:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("data.txt")
val counts = lines.reduceByValue((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)
```

Given that Spark is designed to process large amounts of data efficiently, it  seems counter intuitive to always have to perform an additional step of converting a list into a map and then reducing by key, instead of simply being able to reduce by value?

Comment: What would you have that logic do?

Comment: There is `rdd.reduce()`. Its just not called `reduceByValue`. You do not need to do that extra map. So you can just do - `lines.reduce((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh - thank you, that is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh `lines.reduce((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)` will just concatenate all the strings into one long string, I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP meant.

Comment: @TzachZohar Well... I think OP is asking about whether he can reduce a `RDD` without transforming it into a `PairRDD` or not. As for what type of entities that RDD has, that does not seem to be important. His reduce function will change accordingly.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh The OP clearly intended the second piece of code to be equivalent to the first. The problem here isn't the types (or at least not just that), but the fact that the first piece of code sums up the *values* of the key-value pairs (i.e. the 1s) that share the same key, not the keys itself. Your suggested code would sum up the items in the collection, which is something quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this "additional step" doesn't really cost much (see more details at the end) - it doesn't shuffle the data, and it is performed together with other transformations: transformations can be "pipelined" as long as they don't change the partitioning.

Second - the API you suggest seems very specific for **counting** - although you suggest `reduceByValue` will take a binary operator `f: (Int, Int) => Int`, your suggested API assumes each value is *mapped* to the value `1` before applying this operator for all identical values - an assumption that is hardly useful in any scenario other than counting. Adding such specific APIs would just bloat the interface and is never going to cover all use cases anyway (what's next - `RDD.wordCount`?), so it's better to give users minimal building blocks (along with good documentation).

Lastly - if you're not happy with such low-level APIs, you can use Spark-SQL's DataFrame API to get some higer-level APIs that will hide these details - that's one of the reasons DataFrames exist:

```
val linesDF = sc.textFile("file.txt").toDF("line")
val wordsDF = linesDF.explode("line","word")((line: String) => line.split(" "))
val wordCountDF = wordsDF.groupBy("word").count()
```

**EDIT**: as requested - some more details about why the performance impact of this map operation is either small or entirely negligibile:

- First, I'm assuming you *are* interested in producing **the same result** as the map -> reduceByKey code would produce (i.e. word count), which means *somewhere* the mapping from each record to the value `1` must take place, otherwise there's nothing to perform the summing function `(v1, v2) => v1 + v2` on (that function takes `Int`s, they must be created somewhere).
- To my understanding - you're just wondering why this has to happen as a *separate map operation*
- So, we're actually interested in **the overhead of adding another map operation**

Consider these two functionally-identical Spark transformations:

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = ???
/*(1)*/ rdd.map(s => s.length * 2).collect()
/*(2)*/ rdd.map(s => s.length).map(_ * 2).collect()
```

**Q**: Which one is faster? 
**A**: They perform the same

Why? Because as long as two consecutive transformations on an RDD do not change the partitioning (and that's the case in your original example too), Spark will group them together, and perform them within the same task. So, *per record*, the difference between these two will come down to the difference between:

```
/*(1)*/ s.length * 2
/*(2)*/ val r1 = s.length; r1 * 2
```

Which is *negligible*, especially when you're discussing distributed execution on large datasets, where execution time is dominated by things like shuffling, de/serialization and IO.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "doesn't really cost much"? Given a file with 1 million lines would that not result in 1 million additional operations compared to the rdd.reduce() function Sarvesh Kumar Singh pointed out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `lines.reduce((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)` is _NOT_ what you want here - it will _concatenate_ all the strings in `lines`, resulting in one huge string returned to the driver application (or an OutOfMemoryError for large datasets). I'll edit my answer to show why `map` costs little in this context.